# Setting array formula until last column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a formula as follows in google sheets:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F2:F),IFERROR(SPLIT(REPT("PAID ",F2:F)&REPT("- ",(24-F2:F))," ")),))
```

This formula will show paid according to number of paid in the cell and show "-" to the cells in the rest column. For now, this formula is only applicable for columns. I dont want like that, I want this formula to be used until the last column because the number of columns will be increased every year. I dont know whether this should be done in Google App Script or what. Anything should be fine to solve my problems. I have attached some images to explain myself clearly. Thanks in advance.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bM8l6JefFsPrlJnTWf56wOhnuSjdIwg3hMbY1tN1Zp8/edit#gid=1775459006 - Link to google sheets

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the sheet "JALAN SANGGUL 4" as an example. Then you will need to apply to all of the other sheets that have the same structure.

Replace your current G1 formula with this:

`=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Configuration!P2:P,Configuration!P2:P<>""))`

Replace your current G2 formula with this:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F2:F),IFERROR(SPLIT(REPT("PAID ",F2:F)&REPT("- ",(COUNTA(FILTER(G1:1,G1:1<>""))-F2:F))," ",1,1)),))`

The added `FILTER` in each constrains things to only areas where data exists. By counting where only data exists instead of using a set "24" in the second `REPT` clause, you'll always get dashes going only as far as there are months in Row 1.